# Flutter Project Xcode release run issue

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter

I'm using m1 chip macbook. When I start my flutter with debug mode it's okay. But when it's in release mode I got this 2 Swift compiler errors in XCode. My flutter version is:  2.10.4.
I already tried `pod install`, `pod deintegrate`, `pod update` etc..

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'Firebase'


'FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

Replace the firebase packages to the latest versions.

```
// verions could be not actual
firebase_database: ^4.0.0
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
firebase_analytics: ^6.0.0
firebase_core: ^0.5.0
firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
```

1. Remove ios/Pods folder.
2. Copy PodFile (since you have some customised code)
3. Remove Podfile and Podfile.lock
4. Remove pubspec.lock
5. Run `pod cache clean —all` in terminal
6. Run `flutter clean` in terminal
7. Run `flutter pub get` in terminal
8. Copy the backed up Podfile, mainly the customised code, back to newly regenerated Podfile
9. Run `pod install` in terminal

You can check other recommendations in this [issue on Github](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/3272#issuecomment-695951468).

Comment: still not working

Comment: Check the link to try other ways like down or upgrading flutter/xcode versions. Try to remove all Firebase packages and trigger and then to reinstall etc.